# angular component, check if attribute exists

Tags: angular

Say I have an angular component ie `<this-thing></this-thing>` which does it's thing.

Now I want to add something extra to it, ie `<this-thing glows></this-thing>`
I would like the component to change a little if the **glow** attribute is there.

I have managed to do it via `<this-thing [glows]="true"></this-thing>` and in the component I have

```
@Input() public set glows(value: boolean) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

But that becomes too verbose.

If glows attribute is not on the component, then it's false and if it is, then true.

Is there a better way to acheive this?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `@Attribute` and `@optional` in constructor [see the docs](https://angular.io/api/core/Attribute)

```
constructor(@Optional() @Attribute('glow') glow: any) {
  console.log(glow)
  console.log(glow==undefined)
}

<hello glow></hello> //give you '',false
<hello></hello> //give you null,true
```

Comment: this is the exact answer. Thank you! Works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what you are trying to achieve. If it is just a boolean value to use in the component/template I don't think you need the setter, so that

```
@Input() glows : boolean;
```

in the **this-thing.component.ts** would be sufficient.

In the **this-thing.component.html** you could then bind a specific class to the dom element with **ngClass**

```
<div [ngClass]="{'glows': glows}">This glows if true</div>
```

this-thing.component.css

```
.glows {
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

Comment: Thank you yax, and welcome. I already had an @Input solution but wanted something that didnt take variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the [@HostBinding](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding) decorator which allows you to change the attribute later inside your code.

Example code for `glows` attribute in the component code

```
@HostBinding('attr.glows')
public glows: boolean;

this.glows = true; // Sets the glows attribute
this.glows = false; // Removes the glows attribute
```

Example code for `glows` attribute in the component styles

```
:host([glows]) {
  /* Custom styles for component when the attribute is present */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I kinda had this setup already with the @Input decorator. I wanted a pure if there or if not there solution. Much appriciated.